# NodeJS backend setup

Tags: node.js, express

I basically followed this tutorial to build my first nodeJS application

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

When type in "localhost", it give me such error

```
TypeError: Object function parseUrl(req){
var parsed = req._parsedUrl

 if (fresh(req, parsed)) {
   return parsed
 }

 parsed = fastparse(req.url)

 if (parsed.auth && !parsed.protocol && parsed.href.indexOf('//') !== -1) {
   // This parses pathnames, and a strange pathname like //r@e should work
   parsed = fastparse(req.url.replace(/@/g, '%40'))
 }

 return req._parsedUrl = parsed
} has no method 'original'
   at serveStatic (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-                static/index.js:63:32)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]     (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at trim_prefix (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:13)
   at /home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:238:9
   at Function.proto.process_params (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:313:12)
   at /home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:229:12
   at Function.match_layer (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
   at next (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:190:10)
   at methodOverride (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/method-override/index.js:63:14)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]     (/home/robin/Desktop/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
```

I do not have a clue what it is.
My backend code:

```
"express": "^4.10.4"
```

index.js for initialize whole application

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('./config/db');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

mongoose.connect(db.url); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
require('./app/routes')(app); // configure our routes
app.listen(port);               
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
exports = module.exports = app;
```

nerd.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Nerd', {
    name : {type : String, default: ''}
});
```

// app/routes.js

```
// grab the nerd model we just created
var Nerd = require('./models/nerd');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/nerds', function(req, res) {
        // use mongoose to get all nerds in the database
        Nerd.find(function(err, nerds) {

            // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. 
                            // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(nerds); // return all nerds in JSON format
        });
    });

    // route to handle creating goes here (app.post)
    // route to handle delete goes here (app.delete)

    // frontend routes =========================================================
    // route to handle all angular requests
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
    });
};
```

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Show us your actual code, and the versions of Express used.  (Check your package.json file.)

Comment: @Brad The error occur on the http://localhost:8080 page. Do you think it is problem on the front end route or the backend route. I will post my code.

Comment: With `res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html')`, is that path accessible? Is the path accessible in `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`?